# OnPropertyChanged event doesn't toggle Button Visibility

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, event-handling

I have a button which only should be active if the given text above it is a valid URL, i got the correct regex and also a OnPropertyChanged method in which i set the button Visibility to true (it gets converted to visibility in the xaml file)...

Although i set the button visibility to true nothing changes

ViewModel Code:

```
    private bool m_isSaveButtonVisible = true;

    public bool IsSaveButtonVisible
    {
      get => m_isSaveButtonVisible;
      set 
      {
        m_isSaveButtonVisible = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("???"); //i don't know exactly what to call here?
      }
    }

...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
      if (MeetingRole == WebRTCMeetingRole.Join)
      {
        if (Url != m_currentUrl)
        {
          m_currentUrl = Url;
          if (Regex.Match(m_currentUrl, URL_PATTERN, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
          {
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, e: args); //should set true
          }
          else
          {
             PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, e: args); //should set false
          }
        } 
      }    
    }
```

XAML Code:

```
     <TextBlock Text="{x:Static p:Resources.webrtc_url}" Foreground="White" FontSize="18" Margin="0 0 0 10"/>
      <c:WatermarkTextBox attached:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsUrlFocused}"
                          Foreground="White" FontSize="19" WatermarkForeground="{x:Static co:Colors.Trout}"
                          Margin="0 0 0 30" Text="{Binding Url, Mode=TwoWay}"
                          Watermark="{x:Static p:Resources.webrtc_url_hint}" WatermarkHorizontalAlignment="Left" HasFocus="True" SelectAll="True"
                          EnterCommand="{Binding SaveCommand, Mode=OneTime}" />
...
<c:IconButton Text="{Binding ConfirmButtonText, Mode=OneWay}" TextAlignment="Center" Foreground="White" FontSize="16"
                    Background="{x:Static co:Colors.DarkOrange}" Margin="0 0 0 8"
                    Command="{Binding SaveCommand, Mode=OneTime}"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsSaveButtonVisible, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Does anybody know why the button visibility isn't set ?

What should happen is, when someone writes a valid URL in the Textfield the savebutton should appear

through the OnPropertyChange i already get noticed when somebody writes something in the textfield the problem is that i cant toggle the button out of this function because it doesn't set the visibility and i don't know why

Comment: Assuming that SetProperty calls OnPropertyChanged, your overridden OnPropertyChanged method does not fire the PropertyChanged event. Besides that, the method should *only* fire the PropertyChanged and not do anything else, especially not set any (other) properties.

Comment: Okey, but how do i pass the value (true or false) with the PropertyChanged event

Comment: Whenever you use `new` as in to shadow, like `public new event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;`, then you are probably doing something wrong.

Comment: I suspect that the parent `PropertyChanged` is firing and/or the attached handler.

Comment: Well it only gets Implemented in the BindableBase Class in which i can't change anything.
In there it is virtual so i override it, the problem is the is also the EventHandly implemented which is public and all but somehow i can't use it because of the error CS0079

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Property changed just notifies WPF that a property has changed. Nothing more.

so:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private bool m_isSaveButtonVisible = true;

public bool IsSaveButtonVisible
{
    get => m_isSaveButtonVisible;
    set 
    {
        m_isSaveButtonVisible = value;
        // if somebody listens to PropertyChanged we tell him IsSaveButtonVisible has changed
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(IsSaveButtonVisible)));
    }
}
```

Should be enough.

Comment: I always get a NullReferenceException on PropertyChanged

Comment: If you call a method with "?.", really?
And did you implement the interface "INotifyPropertyChanged"? Otherwise WPF does not know, that you support PropertyChanged.

Comment: well with the ? i don't get the exception but the problem that the PropertyChanged is null still remains :/

Comment: Then nobody wants to know your change. Looks like you missed "INotifyPropertyChanged" `public class YourClass : INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: Well the OnPropertyChangedFunction gets called and checks the url and everything the problem is the Invoke part

Comment: You don't need a OnPropertyChangedFunction. Set your IsSaveButtonVisible property. That's enough

Comment: well but how do i then know/check if somebody writes an URL in the textfield

Comment: Your bound TextField/URL property has a setter

Comment: don't i need a polling or something then?

Comment: No. You type in something into your textfield. The setter of your textfield property is called. You calulate (in the setter or if it is more complex you call a function) and set your IsSaveButtonVisible property and thats it.

Comment: Thank you very much man, i thought to ... complicated and i didn't know that i can put this type of code in the setter